# Vaadin combobox getValue() not getting what i want

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, combobox, vaadin

So i'm trying to get the selected value from a combobox  that holds register numbers for cars. So that the user can choose AAA-111, BBB-222 and so on.

Now i would like to be able to get a hold of which value the the user has chosen in the combobox, but i can't seem to find a way to get it in the "AAA-111" form. Vaadin wants to give it as "entiteetit.Korjaustiedot@4024af35" when I use getValue(). And i have no use of that.

I would like to be able to code it so its like: ok, "AAA-111" is chosen, now get AAA-111's info on the screen at the press of a button. Any ideas how to get the value from the combobox right?

```
ComboBox select = new ComboBox("Choose car");

container = new BeanItemContainer<Korjaustiedot>(Korjaustiedot.class, korjaukset); // gets the data from my mysql database

    select.setContainerDataSource(container); //puts the data from the List <Korjaustiedot> into the container

    select.setItemCaptionPropertyId("registernumber"); //chooses the data from the column "registernumber"

    this.addComponent(select); 
select.addValueChangeListener(event -> // Java 8
    this.addComponent(new Label("Selected " +
        event.getProperty().getValue()))); 
// this label only shows: Selected entiteetit.Korjaustiedot@4024af35
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create a combobox in the same way you do, you do the following:

1. Create collection of items - Cars - that will be contained in your combobox - `BeanItemContainer<Korjaustiedot>(Korjaustiedot.class, korjaukset)`. Note that it is not collection of strings which will be displayed but those are real model objects such as Users, Cars, Accounts etc.
2. You say how item will be displayed in combobox will be represented in combobox. Instead of whole object, there is just string representation. There are several options to choose from, but in your case you say that "registernumber" field of each item will be used as item string representation. You do it via `select.setItemCaptionPropertyId("registernumber")`.
3. If you access selected item via `getProperty().getValue()` you are returned not string representation of selected item which client can see. You are returned whole Car object instead. Thus, if you call `toString()` on it you get `"entiteetit.Korjaustiedot@4024af35"`since it is composite object and not string. If you want registration number you can read it as a field from object you get through get`Property().getValue()`.

Nice description of containers and item collections can be found in Book of Vaadin - [Collecting Items in Containers](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/datamodel.container.html)

Comment: Ok, thank you! I understand it much better now. But how do I get the selected "registernumber"-field from the "entiteetit.Korjaustiedot@4024af35"-object?

Comment: Well it is the very same object of type Korjaustiedot you put in the combobox, you only need to cast it and then you can use it however you want. You can cast it like ((Korjaustiedot)Property().getValue()).getRegisterNumber()

Comment: Thank you for your help! I finally solved it by making a for loop for taking the registernumbers from the List <Korjaustiedot> and adding them in the for loop into the combobox with the addItem function. Like this:

`
private List<Korjaustiedot> korjaukset = null; //this is higher up in the code and here only for clarity

ComboBox select = new ComboBox("Choose car");

for(Korjaustiedot korjaustiedot:korjaukset) {
     Object fieldValue = korjaustiedot.getRekisteritunnus(); 
     select.addItem(fieldValue);
 }`

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the answer from Vojtech Ruzicka or you can cast the getValue method to your class and it should work.

```
select.addValueChangeListener(event->{
this.addComponent(new Label("Selected " + (Korjaustiedot)this.getValue()))})
```

You don't need the event to do this, you will only need to Override the toString method of your class.